# Spring security authentication always return 401

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

I have a problem with authentication in spring.
I have authentication filter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
private final RefreshTokenProvider refreshTokenProvider;
private final AccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider = new AccessTokenProvider();

public AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, RefreshTokenProvider refreshTokenProvider) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    this.refreshTokenProvider = refreshTokenProvider;
    setFilterProcessesUrl(SecurityConstants.AUTH_SIGN_IN_PATH);
}


@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
                                            HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    try {
        SingInRequest singInRequest = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), SingInRequest.class);

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(singInRequest.getUsername(), singInRequest.getPassword());

        return authenticationManager.authenticate(authRequest);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }


}

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                        HttpServletResponse res,
                                        FilterChain chain,
                                        Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
    //

}
```

Implementation UserDetailsService

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private final PasswordEncoder encoder;
    private final UserQueryRepository userQueryRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userQueryRepository.findUserByUsername(username)
                .map(this::getUserDetails)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User with username " + username + " not found"));
    }

    private UserDetails getUserDetails(UserDto user) {
        return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.builder()
                .username(user.getUsername())
                .authorities(convertAuthorities(user))
                .password(encoder.encode(user.getPassword()))
                .disabled(!user.isActive())
                .build();
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> convertAuthorities(UserDto user) {
        return user.getRoles().stream().map(role ->
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.toString())
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

And SecurityConfig class

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserQueryRepository userQueryRepository;
    private final RefreshTokenProvider refreshTokenProvider;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/book/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), refreshTokenProvider))
                .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl(passwordEncoder(), userQueryRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return source;
    }
```

And if I try with the postman send an auth request with good credentials, in debugger mode everything works fine (AuthFilter and UserDetailsService) but the server returns 401 and successfulAuthentication method in Authfilter doesn't invoke.

---

Request received for POST '/auth/sing-in':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@27b774b2

servletPath:/auth/sing-in
pathInfo:null
headers:
content-type: application/json
user-agent: PostmanRuntime/7.25.0
accept: */*
cache-control: no-cache
postman-token: c5bb3320-9c22-4d3d-93e9-628fe0e6f82a
host: localhost:9000
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 54

Security filter chain: [
WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
HeaderWriterFilter
LogoutFilter
AuthenticationFilter
AuthorizationFilter
RequestCacheAwareFilter
SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
SessionManagementFilter
ExceptionTranslationFilter
FilterSecurityInterceptor
]

---

2020-06-13 20:52:42.048  INFO 9956 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:126}] to 127.0.0.1:27017
2020-06-13 20:52:42.258  INFO 9956 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] Spring Security Debugger                 :

---

Request received for POST '/error':

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@fafe057

servletPath:/error
pathInfo:null
headers:
content-type: application/json
user-agent: PostmanRuntime/7.25.0
accept: */*
cache-control: no-cache
postman-token: c5bb3320-9c22-4d3d-93e9-628fe0e6f82a
host: localhost:9000
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 54

Security filter chain: [
WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
HeaderWriterFilter
LogoutFilter
AuthenticationFilter
AuthorizationFilter
RequestCacheAwareFilter
SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
SessionManagementFilter
ExceptionTranslationFilter
FilterSecurityInterceptor
]

---

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the successfulAuthentication() method. It should look like this.

```
@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                        HttpServletResponse res,
                                        FilterChain chain,
                                        Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(req, res, chain, auth);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

Sorry I didn't notice that 'successfulAuthentication doesn't invoke'. Could you please share the stack trace in debug mode using

```
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
```

Comment: I added stack trace

Comment: Can you also share the code of your User class that implements UserDetails

Comment: I use this class https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.15.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html

Comment: I want to know when you are creating the user did you set the attributes enabled = true, accountNonLocked = true, credentialsNonExpired = true, accountNonExpired = true